# React routes are not rendering

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I am working on a dashboard that has a sidebar with different routes and I initialized them in an array as follows:

```
const sideBar = [
{
  id: 0,
  name: "Add Company",
  icon: admin_add_company,
  path: `${url}register`,
  exact: true,
  component: () => <div>The 1st component</div>,
},
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Configuration",
  icon: configuration_icon,
  path: `${url}/configuration`,
  exact: false,
  component: () => <div>The 2nd component</div>,
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "Delivery",
  icon: delivery_admin_icon,
  path: `${url}/delivery`,
  exact: false,
  component: () => <div>The 3rd component</div>,
},
```

];

And I am looping through the different routes to change the content next to the sidebar according to the select route and here is how it is implemented:

```
  {sideBar.map((route, index) => (
            <Route
              key={index}
              name={route.name}
              path={route.path}
              exact={route.exact}
              url={url}
              component={route.component}
            />
          ))}
```

and here are the links that represent all routes:

```
<Nav defaultActiveKey={`${url}`} className="flex-column">
            <Nav.Link
              eventKey="register-link"
              active={active.register}
              onClick={() => {
                history.push(url);
                toggleLink({ name: "register", value: true });
              }}
            >
              <img src={admin_add_company} />
              <span>Add Company</span>
            </Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link
              active={active.configuration}
              eventKey="configuration-link"
              onClick={() => {
                history.push(`${url}/configuration`);
                toggleLink({ name: "configuration", value: true });
              }}
            >
              <img src={configuration_icon} />
              <span>Configuration</span>
            </Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link
              active={active.delivery}
              eventKey="delivery-link"
              onClick={() => {
                history.push(`${url}/delivery`);
                toggleLink({ name: "delivery", value: true });
              }}
            >
              <img src={delivery_admin_icon} />
              <span>Delivery</span>
            </Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link
              active={active.partners}
              eventKey="partners-link"
              onClick={() => {
                history.push(`${url}/partners`);
                toggleLink({ name: "partners", value: true });
              }}
            >
              <img src={admin_partners} />
              <span>Partners</span>
            </Nav.Link>
        <Nav>
```

The point is that the routes change properly. Yet, the content of each component never changes or show up. Why could this happen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing / here path: `${url}register`, should be path: `${url}/register`

Comment: Added it but still not working!!

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Route` prop: `component` -> `render`

**edit**

How about when you change your

```
<Nav.Link
    active={active.configuration}
    eventKey="configuration-link"
    onClick={() => {
        history.push(`${url}/configuration`);
        toggleLink({ name: "configuration", value: true });
    }}
>
```

to

```
<Nav.Link
    active={active.configuration}
    eventKey="configuration-link"
    onClick={() => {
        toggleLink({ name: "configuration", value: true });
    }}
    to='/configuration'
>
```

Comment: Oh, I supposed it's the same as `NavLink`. But what about pushing just the specified path, without the url?

Comment: I fixed the issue by wrapping the whole component into Router tag. It worked this way idk why as I already have Router wrapping the index.js

Comment: I didn't see your index.js, but conventionally it is where you render your App component into the static HTML file. So wrapping that into anything doesn't make sense...